# EF & Parallel.ForEach Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I've got method `AddOrUpdateFruitMetaData` which should add or update record in `FruitMetaData` table. 
Unfortunately I'm keep getting an errors:

`Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_FruitMetaData'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.FruitMetaData'. The duplicate key value is (0, COLOR). The statement has been terminated.`

How this is even possible even when I'm trying to find existing record before?

Also using `AddOrUpdate()` from `System.Data.Entity.Migrations` instead of `Add()` is not helping me.

Call stack looks that:

In my main class in `Parallel.ForEach` with multiple `for` loop looking like that:

```
Parallel.ForEach(args)
{
    for(something)
    {
        var fruit = new Fruit();
        fruit.FruitId = uniqueId;
        UpdateOrCreateFruitMetaData(fruit, "Color", "Blue")
    }
}
```

I'm calling method:

```
private void UpdateOrCreateFruitMetaData(Fruit fruit, string metaType, string value)
{
    var fruitMetaData = new FruitMetaData();
    fruitMetaData.FruitId = fruit.FruitId;
    fruitMetaData.MetaType = metaType;
    fruitMetaData.Value = value;

    using (var db = Context.DB)
    {
        db.AddOrUpdateFruitMetaData(fruitMetaData);
    }
}
```

That method is using `Context.DB` which is object containing `new DBEntity()` and also Dispose(). So my Entity Context is disposed every time.

Then I'm calling next method `AddOrUpdateFruitMetaData()`:

```
AddOrUpdateFruitMetaData(FruitMetaData fruitMetaData)
{
    lock (thisLock)
    {
        try
        {
            var fmd = db.FruitMetaData.Where(x => x.FruitId  == fruitMetaData.FruitId)
                                      .Where(x => x.MetaType == fruitMetaData.MetaType)
                                      .FirstOrDefault();
            if (fmd == null)
                db.FruitMetaData.Add(fruitMetaData);
            else
                fmd.Value = fruitMetaData.Value;


            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error($"AddOrUpdateFruitMetaData. FruitId:{fruitMetaData.FruitId} MetaType:{fruitMetaData.MetaType}", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

[EDIT] To explain `using (var db = Context.DB)` :

My `Context` class contains `DbData DB` Property which looks like that :

```
public DbData DB 
{ 
    get { return new DbData(); } 
}
```

And `DbData` class looks like that:

```
public class DbData : IDisposable
{
    private DBEntity db;

    public DbData()
    {
        db = new FruitDBEntity();
    }

    // This class contains that problematic method
    AddOrUpdateFruitMetaData(FruitMetaData fruitMetaData)(...)
}
```

So each time I'm getting Context.DB property I am actually creating new Entity Context.

Comment: EF context is NOT thread safe. See if you made some errors in synchronization. Especially this 'thisLook' variable which is not presented across same Parallel call but somewhere else.

Comment: @eocron : That's why I am creating new DbContext when I am calling `AddOrUpdateFruitMetaData`. If that's also not working what else I can do?

Comment: And where did you actually do this? I don't see any code related to creation of context but some singleton property.

Comment: This is a classic race - you have two or more threads saying "does X exist?", then considering the answer to that question (no), and then deciding "okay, I'll add X since it didn't exist".

Comment: Also, check if you specified autoincrement for Primary Key. If you don't set it - you should specify PK each time you create object.

Comment: @eocron : I've edited thread to explain `using( var db = Context.DB )`. 
@Damien_The_Unbeliever : Is there any way I can make it to actually work?